# Pedir datos a usuario condicionalmente en PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

### Problema

Usando el Oracle SQL Developer versión `4.1.0.19` estoy pidiendo datos al usuario pero el programa me pide más datos de los necesarios, saltándose las sentencias `if` y `elsif`.

### Código

```
declare
  v_nombre varchar2(500);
  v_caracteres number;
  v_edad number;
begin
  select '&nombre' into v_nombre from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_nombre);
  v_caracteres := length(replace(v_nombre,' ',''));
  --dbms_output.put_line(replace(v_nombre,' ',''));
  if v_caracteres > 50 then
    dbms_output.put_line('Tu nombre parece un poema! tiene ' || v_caracteres || ' letras');
  elsif v_caracteres <= 50 then
    begin
      dbms_output.put_line('Tu nombre tiene '|| v_caracteres || ' letras');
      v_edad := '&edad';
      if v_edad > 17 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Ese mi chavoruco ¿Qué transacción por tu base de datos?');
       else
         dbms_output.put_line('Estás chavo!');
      end if;
    end;
  end if;
  EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('diagonal cero');
end;
/
```

He probado igual usando `:` pero el resultado es similar.
Espero alguien conozca alguna manera de solventar este problema.
Entiendo que el código no tiene error, pero el resultado deseado sería que al ponerle un nombre con más de 50 caracteres ya no pidiera nada más.

Comment: ¿Todavía estas buscando una respuesta para esa pregunta?

Comment: siempre amigo, por eso no tiene respuesta aceptada

Comment: ¿Has pensado ofrecer una recompensa o actualizar tu pregunta con algún avance que hayas logrado?  quizás también valdría la pena el agregar algo para clarificar porque las respuestas del `2016` que ha recibido tu pregunta no han sido aceptadas.

Answer (score 3):

No se puede. PL/SQL no es interactivo. Lo que sucede es que SQL Plus (o el programa que uses para comunicarte con la DB) acepta "parámetros". Estos funcionan de la siguiente manera:

1. SQL Plus pide un valor por cada `&parámetro`
2. Reemplaza cada parámetro con el valor ingresado
3. Manda el texto resultante a la DB para su ejecución

Por lo tanto, la DB nunca ve los `&`, sino que recibe el código con el parámetro ya reemplazado. El pedido de los parámetros es anterior a la ejecución del código.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en todo lo que comentas, pero lo que busco es alguna modallidad de sql developer, programa o truco o incluso bug para que me pida los parámetros conforme se van necesitando. Gracias por tu comprensión, y de todos modos, aunque tu respuesta no es la aceptada, le pondré que ha sido útil con una flecha arriba. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

para pedir los datos en oracle 10g seria asi:

```
SELECT last_name, salary, hire_date FROM employees
   WHERE last_name=:Apellido
```

Comment: Como ya habìa escrito: He probado igual usando `:` pero el resultado es similar.

Answer (score -2):

No olvides el espacio despues del >, = o lo que sea que uses.

```
select last_name, salary from employees 
where salary > :salario
```